# Can I connect my XLR mic to my mobile via an XLR -> USB cable via OTG?

Tags: hardware

I have an XLR mic. I want to connect it to my mobile phone. But even after using all kinds of solutions / cables / connectors my mobile's audio (TRRS) socket is not detecting the mic.

I was thinking of bypassing the audio socket by going in for a USB based solution using an XLR -> USB cable (https://www.amazon.in/gp/product/B06XBMMC1D)

If I use this cable and a OTG connector, will my XLR mic work in Android? The cable has a microcontroller based chipset inside it which converts analog signals to digital (that's what the manufacturer says).

My USB pc webcam mic works perfectly on my mobile when connected via a OTG connector. So will the above solution also work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went ahead and bought the XLR -> USB cable and IT WORKS through the OTG connector on my Redmi 4 mobile. But there is a lot of background static in the recordings.